# No prompt after successful ssh login

Tags: ssh

After a successful login to my VPS the command prompt doesn't get displayed. I've ran ssh with -vvv and sshd with debug output, absolutely nothing is amiss.

The VPS is Ubuntu 11.04, the client Ubuntu 11.10, sitting behind a router. The strange thing is my laptop (also Ubuntu 11.10) behind that same router connects and gets the command prompt no problem.

/var/log/auth output is [here](http://pastebin.com/86d9HHH9)

ssh -vvv output is [here](http://pastebin.com/zhngQ9Zt)

Since the laptop gets the command prompt without issues, I'm guessing the problem is with my desktop. Can I do like a flush of everything ssh related in case I screwed something up? I've tried deleting ~/.ssh/knownhosts but that didn't do it.

Comment: what type of VPS ? can you post the output of ssh -vvv the logs do not show much.

Comment: added the -vvv output. VPS is OpenVZ. like I said, the other machine connects to it without a hitch.

Comment: Only other issue I can think of is with your user ssh config. Please could you provide the contents if $HOME/.ssh/config . Make sure there is no sensitive content in there.

Comment: haven't got one, there is no config file in my home/.ssh dir and neither is there on the other client, the one that works. the /etc/ssh/ssh_config files are stock and identical on both clients.

Comment: could it be that the VPS has some block access from host xy thingy? that would explain the sound of silence...? hosts.allow and .deny are ok, so maybe purge stored keys from previous connections or something? where would I look fot those?

Comment: created a key with ssh-keygen for passwordless login, uploaded it to the VPS, still a no-go. same procedure worked for the laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. ufw was acting out. Although `sudo ufw status` returns "disabled", running `sudo ufw disable` fixed it. I haz no explanation for it, after wasting way too much time with this I'm just happy it works.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the same issue I saw, but on Ubuntu they require bash to be *run in login mode* to set the prompt, as such *unless* you have `login=yes` in the `sshd_config` you will not get a prompt.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of others that end up with similar problems, here is another solution:

Our embedded system was allowing ssh connections, but was not giving a shell prompt. By setting the logging output to DEBUG3 in `sshd_config` and checking the `/var/log/messages`, we were able to determine that the ssh server was going to pause for about 100 years!

Our embedded system never initialised its clock, so it thought it was 1917. Because the ssh client message was from the future, the server was waiting for its own time to catch up to it. We resolved the problem by setting the time (using `date`) and restarting the server (using `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`).

Comment: seconding this--check the date and time settings on your server!! I recently experienced a similar issue due to daylight savings time

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on an embedded device. The problem was that `/dev/pts` was not mounted.

```
sudo mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you're logged in, do `echo "$PS1" | od -bc`. Your prompt, `PS1` (assuming `bash`) is set by your startup scripts. Where do you set up your prompt? Perhaps you need to add your `PS1` definition to `~/.ssh/environment` or `~/.ssh/rc` on the target. See `man ssh` and `man sshd`.

Comment: tried it, set up a simple prompt in ~/.ssh/environment. same result. from what I understand, if it's a server config issue, then none of the PC's would've been able to get the prompt, but they do. all except this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you running sshd as a systemd managed process, then after making any changes to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` you must execute `systemctl restart sshd` for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the option `-T` from the ssh command

Comment: Hey, João, welcome to the site!  As this stands, it looks almost more like a comment than an answer.  Please [edit] to expand.  Don't just give a one-liner; explain why you right, ideally with citations.  Answers without explanation are subject to removal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had done the brilliance of changing configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and setting `PermitTTY no`.

Editing that file to set `PermitTTY yes` and restarting `sshd` solved the problem.

Hope it helps someone, cheers.